# How to solve this modulus question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

IS there any solutions for this equation?

।x+3। - ।4-x। = ।8+x।

Do we have to consider separately for each case like,   ।x+3। <0 and ।x+3।>0 and go on?

Answer (score 1):

We can rewrite as $$|x-(-3)|=|x-4|+|x-(-8)|$$
and interpret geometrically as:

LHS= distance from $x$ to $-3$

RHS= (distance from $x$ to $4$)+ (distance from $x$ to $-8$)

In the end there will still be some case analysis, but at least it's not 8 cases.

Comment: can we have a solution for x?

Comment: Yes, we can, and I'm sure you can find it.

Comment: If all you care about is the answer, and not the method, just use [alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Cx%2B3%7C%3D%7Cx-4%7C%2B%7Cx%2B8%7C).

Comment: Making any progress, Complex Guy?